# VLC's http interface and other web based media players

Tags: vlc-media-player, media-player, media-center

VLC has this nice http interface. I will say it is nice that it has a http interface, but the interface layout is a little bit rude.

Do you know of other http "skins" available for VLC in http mode ?

Do you know of other media player/center that can be controlled thru a HTTP interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html)

Plays on Windows, Linux, OSX and Wii.